# How to get knockoutjs visible binding work with expressions containing observable strings?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Lets say there is an observable string stringVal defined in the view model.

`data-bind="visible:!stringVal()"` or any other expression containing stringVal() doesnt work. The error thrown is that a function stringVal() is expected in the view model.

Similar expression easily works with boolean observables.

Comment: can you check using visible:  stringVal() != 'yourStringToCheck' ?

Comment: Show your view-model

Comment: i'm not sure tough check this jsfiddle.net/h6dy46s7/2 .

Comment: @supercool I am looking for the opposite scenario about which you are talking in your code comment there..

Comment: simply you can use `!` as mentioned in comment .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably your version of Knockout. It works with versions 3.0+ but not with 2.x

```js
function myViewModel() {
  self = this;
  self.stringval = ko.observable("hello");
}

ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<h1 data-bind="visible: !stringval()">
    <span data-bind="text: stringval()"></span>
    <span>yo</span>
</h1>

<input data-bind="value: stringval" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
http://jsfiddle.net/w00t_/h6dy46s7/1/

HTML:

```
<h1 data-bind="visible: notstringval">
    <span data-bind="text: stringval()"></span>
    <span>yo</span>
</h1>
```

JS:

```
function myViewModel() {
    self = this;
    self.stringval = ko.observable("hello");
    self.notstringval = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        return !self.stringval();
    })
}

ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
```

Comment: Sure, this can be done. But the question is can visible directly use a string observable.